# Java Spring annotation error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm writing a web application using Spring MVC, I have en error, and I don`t know what's causing it.

I was looking for any solution but adding annotations like `@Component` didn't help.

Here is the code of classes:

**Repository class:**

```
@Repository("UserRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

@Query("Insert INTO User Values(email,password)")
public User AddUser(@Param("email") String email, @Param("password") String password);
}
```

**Controller class:**

```
@RestController
public class UserActionController {



private UserRepository userservice;

@Autowired
public  UserActionController(UserRepository userservice)
{
    this.userservice = userservice;
}


@RequestMapping(value = { "/zaloguj" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView logowanie(@RequestParam String action) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Injected MVC title");
    model.addObject("message", "This is default page!");
    model.setViewName("zaloguj");   
    userservice.AddUser("test", "test");
    return model;
}
}
```

And the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userActionController' defined in file [C:\Users\bartlomiej.zuk\workspaceEclipse4\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\examplespringproject\WEB-INF\classes\com\mkyong\web\controller\UserActionController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.mkyong.dao.UserRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.mkyong.dao.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mkyong.dao.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mkyong.dao.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 24 more
```

Comment: try placing @Qualifier("UserRepository") on the constructor  UserActionController

Answer (score 1):

> No qualifying bean of type [com.mkyong.dao.**UserRepository**]

This means that spring could not instantiate the `UserRepository`. You somehow should tell the spring where's your `repositories` location. For example, you should have a `Data Access Configuration` like following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.mkyong.dao")
public class DataConfig {
    // Put your DataSource, EntityManagerFactory, PlatformTransactionManager, etc here
}
```

`basePackages="com.mkyong.dao"` tells the spring container to look for repositories in `com.mkyong.dao` package. Also, when you're using `Spring Data`, there is no need for `@Repository` annotations.